# Why python mock patch doesn't work?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, nose

I have two files

spike.py

```
class T1(object):
    def foo(self, afd):
        return "foo"

    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo(1)


def bar():
    return "bar"
```

test_spike.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from spike import T1, bar


class TestStuff(TestCase):
    @patch('spike.T1.foo', MagicMock(return_value='patched'))
    def test_foo(self):
        foo = T1().get_foo()
        self.assertEqual('patched', foo)

    @patch('spike.bar')
    def test_bar(self, mock_obj):
        mock_obj.return_value = 'patched'
        bar = bar()
        self.assertEqual('patched', bar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run `python test_spike.py`, the first test case would pass, but the second would fail.
and I switch to use `nosetests test_spike.py`, then both two are failed.

I don't understand how this happened? These cases supposed to pass all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python mock patch doesn't work as expected for public method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987973/python-mock-patch-doesnt-work-as-expected-for-public-method)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For *test_foo* you are not using patch correctly. You should be using it like this:

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    @patch.object(T1, 'foo', MagicMock(return_value='patched'))
    def test_foo(self):
        foo = T1().get_foo()
        self.assertEqual('patched', foo)
```

that gives me:

```
nosetests test_spike.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Now the second example does not work because you import bar function (get a reference to it) and then try to mock it. When you mock something you can't change what your variables hold (reference to original function). To fix this you should use @falsetru suggested method like:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from mock import patch
import spike


class TestFoo(TestCase):
    @patch('spike.bar')
    def test_bar(self, mock_obj):
        mock_obj.return_value = 'patched'
        value = spike.bar()
        self.assertEqual('patched', value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

this gives me:

```
python test_spike.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

But when I try to run it with nose I get:

```
 nosetests test_spike.py
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_bar (src.test_spike.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zilva/envs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/zilva/git/test/src/test_spike.py", line 11, in test_bar
    self.assertEqual('patched', value)
AssertionError: 'patched' != 'bar'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

This happends because I am patching not in the right place. My directory structure is:

```
test/
└── src/
    ├── spike.py
    ├── test_spike.py
    └── __init__.py
```

and I run tests from src directory so I should be patching using path from project root directory like:

```
@patch('src.spike.bar')
```

and this would give me:

```
nosetests test_spike.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

or if I am at test directory:

```
nosetests src/test_spike.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Answer (score 64):

Access `bar` using `spike.bar`. Imported `bar` is not affected by `mock.patch`.

```
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from spike import T1
import spike # <----


class TestShit(TestCase):
    @patch('spike.T1.foo', MagicMock(return_value='patched'))
    def test_foo(self):
        foo = T1().get_foo()
        self.assertEqual('patched', foo)

    @patch('spike.bar')
    def test_bar(self, mock_obj):
        mock_obj.return_value = 'patched'
        bar = spike.bar() # <-----
        self.assertEqual('patched', bar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for `python test_spike.py`, but why it still not works for `nosetests test_spike.py`?

Comment: @LeoShi, Sorry, I don't know about that.

Answer (score 38):

To elaborate on the very helpful top answer, let me paraphrase the official documentation for [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

```py
a.py
    class SomeClass:
        ...

b.py
    import a
    from a import SomeClass
    def some_function():
        a.SomeClass()
        SomeClass()
```

If you write `mock.patch('a.SomeClass')`, this will affect the first line of `some_function`. If you write `mock.patch('b.SomeClass')`, this will affect the second line.

Comment: Thank you, this made the difference for me! instead of patching `core_module.core_function` I had to patch `module_that_im_testing.core_function`, since the module that I'm testing also imported the function.

Comment: It's easiest to patch functions globally if you always call them with qualified names. For example, inside of `module_that_im_testing`, don't write `core_function(...)`, but instead write `core_module.core_function(...)`. That way, you don't have to patch `core_function` once for every module where it's used.

Comment: ffs thank you.  This wasn't very intuitive for me, but you made it very clear.