# python mock patch decorator behaves different for class methods and individual functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, decorator, patch

Several times I've ran into a problem with `unittest.mock.patch` decorator. When I tried to mock individual functions from included module, `patch` didn't work. However if functions from included module are collected as class methods, `patch` works perfectly.

Partially this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242862/why-python-mock-patch-doesnt-work) intersects with mine. But there is no good answer for this issue as well.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to describe:

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- helpers.py
|-- main_module.py
|-- tests.py
```

I wrote one function in `helpers.py` as a class method, and another one as an individual function:

```
# helpers.py
class HelperClass():

    def method_a(self):
        return "a"

def function_a():
    return "a"
```

I've included both of them in the main module:

```
# main_module.py    
from helpers import HelperClass, function_a


    def function_which_uses_helper_function():
        a_val = function_a()
        return a_val

    def function_which_uses_helper_class_method():
        a_val = HelperClass().method_a()
        return a_val
```

And finally tests:

```
# tests.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from main_module import function_which_uses_helper_function, function_which_uses_helper_class_method


class TestClass(TestCase):

    @patch('helpers.function_a')
    def test_function_which_uses_helper_function(self, mock_function_a):
        mock_function_a.return_value = "c"
        self.assertEqual(function_which_uses_helper_function(), "c")

    @patch('helpers.HelperClass.method_a')
    def test_function_which_uses_helper_class_method(self, mock_method_a):
        mock_method_a.return_value = "c"
        self.assertEqual(function_which_uses_helper_class_method(), "c")
```

Which gives me these results:

```
$ py.test tests.py
<...>
tests.py .F
<...>
tests.py:11: in test_function_which_uses_helper_function
    self.assertEqual(function_which_uses_helper_function(), "c")
E   AssertionError: 'a' != 'c'
E   - a
E   + c
============ 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.14 seconds ============
```

I'll appreciate any help. Hope this also helps someone :)

Comment: It might clear things up a bit if you renamed `function_a` within the class to `method_a`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @jonrsharpe! Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while I finally understood why my example for function didn't work. The explanations is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch). And [this article](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/) was very useful as well. Considering all of that solution will be:

```
# main_module.py    
import helpers # <- I had to change my import statement


def function_which_uses_helper_function():
    a_val = helpers.function_a()
    return a_val

def function_which_uses_helper_class_method():
    a_val = helpers.HelperClass().method_a()
    return a_val
```

Another solution is to change the way how I mock my function_a, which is:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from main_module import function_which_uses_helper_function, function_which_uses_helper_class
```

```
class TestClass(TestCase):
    
    @patch('main_module.function_a') # <-- !!! I need to mock function in the`main_module`, not in `helpers` !!!
    def test_function_which_uses_helper_function(self, mock_function_a):
        mock_function_a.return_value = "c"
        self.assertEqual(function_which_uses_helper_function(), "c")

    @patch('helpers.HelperClass.function_a')
    def test_function_which_uses_helper_class(self, mock_function_a):
        mock_function_a.return_value = "c"
        self.assertEqual(function_which_uses_helper_class(), "c")
```

I'm sad that I've realized all of that just recently. Hope this helps somebody :)

Comment: That article was, indeed, helpful.