# Python mock patch not reseting the return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing test cases using python mock library.

```
class AddressByPhoneTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_no_content_found_with_mock(self):
        print "this function will mock Contact model get_by_phone to return none"
        with mock.patch('user_directory.models.Contact') as fake_contact:
            print "fake_contact_id ", id(fake_contact)
            conf = { 'get_by_phone.return_value': None }
            fake_contact.configure_mock(**conf)
            resp = self.client.get(reverse('get_address_by_phone'), {'phone_no' : 1234567891})
            self.assertTrue(resp.status_code == 204)

    def test_success_with_mock(self):
        print  "this function will test the address by phone view after mocking model"
        with mock.patch('user_directory.models.Contact') as fake_contact:
            print "fake_contact_id ", id(fake_contact)
            contact_obj = Contact(recent_address_id = 123, best_address_id = 456)
            conf = { 'get_by_phone.return_value': contact_obj }
            fake_contact.configure_mock(**conf)
            resp = self.client.get(reverse('get_address_by_phone'), {'phone_no' : 1234567891})
            resp_body = json.loads(resp.content)
            self.assertTrue(resp_body == {  'recent_address_id' : 123, 
                                            'frequent_address_id' : 456
                                        }
                        )
```

In the second case Contact.get_by_phone is still returning None even though I changed it to return a contact_obj, when I removed the upper test case, this test cases passes but fails otherwise citing the upper reason
Someone help, how can i make the python mock patch to reset the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the real reason for it, but it seems you need to import the parent of the function/class you are testing.

I had written this line in my views.py

```
from user_directory.models import Contact
```

Contact was unaffected by mock.patch. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242862/why-python-mock-patch-doesnt-work). Hence I changed my code to the following and it worked like a charm.

```
def test_no_content_found_with_patch(self):
    print "this function will mock Contact model get_by_phone to return none"
    with mock.patch('user_directory.models.Contact.get_by_phone') as fake_func:
        fake_func.return_value = None
        resp = self.client.get(self.get_address_by_phone, {'phone_no' : 1234567891})
        self.assertTrue(resp.status_code == 204)

def test_success_with_patch(self):
    print  "this function will test the address by phone view after mocking model"
    with mock.patch('user_directory.models.Contact.get_by_phone') as fake_func:
        contact_obj = Contact(recent_address_id = 123, best_address_id = 457)
        fake_func.return_value = contact_obj
        resp = self.client.get(self.get_address_by_phone, {'phone_no' : 1234567891})
        resp_body = json.loads(resp.content)
        self.assertTrue(resp_body == {  'recent_address_id' : contact_obj.recent_address_id, 
                                        'frequent_address_id' : 457
                                    }
                    )
```

See this line

```
with mock.patch('user_directory.models.Contact.get_by_phone') as fake_func
```

Comment: This should work fine, but the original post should work as well. Please update when you can make your original post worked as is, thanks

Comment: @Gang No above doesn't work. Above will work if in my views I do this
from user_directory import models.
and use
models.Contact instead of Contact