# patching class in python does not execute the mock object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, patch

In the below code, When i print SimplClass in mock_simple_class, I do not see the mocked object printed, Instead its the original class. Am i missing something here. I am under the impression patching the object would patch it everywhere in that mock_simple_class context.

```
import mock
from simple.simple import SimpleClass

def simple_test():
    inst = SimpleClass("Junk", "Store")
    result = inst.explode()
    print(result)

@mock.patch("simple.simple.SimpleClass")
def mock_simple_class(mock_class):
    print(mock_class)
    print(SimpleClass)
    mock_class.return_value.explode.return_value = "BOO!"
    simple_test()

mock_simple_class()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20242957/6560549

Comment: As stated by @SuperShoot you need to `import simple` instead of `from ... import ...`. Check the provided link

Comment: put file structure here.