# Pytest fixture for `airflow.operators.python.get_current_context` fails with `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException`

Tags: python, mocking, airflow, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to mock `airflow.operators.python.get_current_context` as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture
def _mock_get_current_context(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        "airflow.operators.python.get_current_context",
        return_value={},
    )
```

This pattern works for all other functions I am mocking, for example `requests.get`, `airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator.execute` and `requests.Response.content`. However, when I call `get_current_context()` in a DAG task, I get the following error:

```
if not _CURRENT_CONTEXT:
    raise AirflowException(
        "Current context was requested but no context was found! "
        "Are you running within an airflow task?"
        )
E       airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Current context was requested but no 
context was found! Are you running within an airflow task?
```

Indicating that the mocking did not work since the source code for `get_current_context()` looks like this:

```
    def get_current_context() -> Context:
        if not _CURRENT_CONTEXT:
            raise AirflowException(
                "Current context was requested but no context was found! "
                "Are you running within an airflow task?"
            )
        return _CURRENT_CONTEXT[-1]
```

Any ideas what can have gone wrong?

Comment: This explained it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242862/why-python-mock-patch-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of tricky (with Airflow). As others noted, it's important to realize [how does mocking work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242862/why-python-mock-patch-doesnt-work). But with Airflow tasks it's even more complicated.

Let's take an example - you have some repository `custom_repo` with a folder `daily` containing your module `dag.py`. Inside this module, there are all the tasks, DAG definition and also top level import `from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context`. Then there is also test folder in your `custom_repo` where you would like to test your tasks and mock the context.

Your approach will not work, so you could think about using sth like:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def _mock_get_current_context(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        "custom_repo.daily.dag.get_current_context",
        return_value={},
    )
```

But this will not work as well as you do not directly import anything from `custom_repo`, you very likely use `DagBag` which allows you to discover your dags within your repo and access different tasks by dag id (and task id). But all dags comes with a randomized name which makes the mocking confusing (in my case the dag module name was sth like `unusual_prefix_91538somerandomid_dag`).

Therefore I would recommend to use sth like this (note that `_CURRENT_CONTEXT` is a list containing the context dictionary):

```py
@pytest.fixture
def _mock_get_current_context(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(
        airflow.operators.python,
        "_CURRENT_CONTEXT",
        [{}],
    )
```

There might be a better (more correct?) way but I am not aware of any.